# Replication in hadoop causes data redundancy then why is pursued in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If Replication causes data redundancy then why is pursued in HDFS

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to ask why we are wasting space with replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cost of storage is very cheap these days. Replication is providing fault tolerance on commodity hardware.